# Do I need to use a Subscription with .valueChanges() when reading data from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Previously using the Real-time Database I have become accustomed to using a Subscription to watch for changes in the database. Cloud Firestore, however, has .valueChanges() that seems to do this automatically so do I still need to use an rxjs Subscription?

My code is below fully working without issues I am asking about `_subscription: Subscription;` and not `.valueChanges().subscribe`

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Observable, pipe, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  _data: any = [];
  _subscription: Subscription;
  itemsDocument_data: AngularFirestoreDocument<any[]>;
  itemsCollection_data: AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>;

  constructor(private _afDB: AngularFirestore) {
    await _dbGeData();
  }

  private async _dbGeData() {
    try {

      if (this._fbData_subscription_User === undefined) {
        this.itemsDocument_users = this._afDB.collection("_myDataPath").doc("_mySecondDatapath");
        this._subscription_data = await this.itemsDocument_data.valueChanges().subscribe((items) => {
          this._data = [];
          for (let i in items) {
            this._data.push = items[i];
          }

          //items (object) is now this._data (Array)

          console.log("items (object)", items);
          console.log("this._data (Array)", this._data);

          return;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("when getting data", e);
      return;
    }

    return;

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._subscription !== undefined) {
      this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: you didnt declare `this._fbData_subscription_Use`, wont it always be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

`valueChanges()` returns an observable, you have to subscribe to it one way or another for anything to actually happen.

Can't you stay within this observable and subscribe at the very last moment (like in the template with the `AyncPipe`) ?